# How to see a GUI program running in a remote Debian server

Tags: debian, remote

I connect to a Debian server using `ssh -i mykey.pem username@ip`. I want to install and run, for example, a browser with a GUI and see the window from my local client, how could I do it? Elinks works, but it's kind of tough to use for navigating the web.

Before flagging this question as duplicate, I have to say that I already tried the instruction in [How do I work with GUI tools over a remote server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9870/how-do-i-work-with-gui-tools-over-a-remote-server).

I also tried login with `ssh -X -i ...` and `ssh -Y -i ...` .

`X11Forwarding yes` is enabled in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (on the remote server).
`ForwardX11 yes` is set in `~/.ssh/config` (local client)

echo $DISPLAY output: (after login, none)

`export DISPLAY=<myip>:0.0`

echo $DISPLAY output: `<myip>:0.0` (after the comment above).

When trying to run xfe I get:
`FXApp::openDisplay: unable to open display <myip>:0.0`

What's wrong? What could I try? Do I have to open any port on my local machine?

Comment: Before exporting DISPLAY, you should ensure it is set: what is the result of `echo $DISPLAY` ? If it contains `localhost`, you should let it unchanged. Most of the time, activating `X11Forwarding` in config and `ssh -X ...` should be sufficient.

Comment: @updated question.

Comment: Thanks, but I meant BEFORE you type `export DISPLAY=...` :) Just log on your server using `ssh -X` then type `echo $DISPLAY` just after you logged in.

Comment: @apaul: done, output is none.

Comment: So I guess the server is not started in init level 5, thus isn't able to run X applications. If you manage this server, you can run `init 5` or modify `/etc/inittab` and restart the server. Else, ask the server admin to set the start init level to level 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are manually setting DISPLAY, you probably need to issue

```
 xhost +
```

on your local machine first. (I know, everyone will flame on about poor security etc, you could refine it a bit, but for testing, this is the most expeditious way to go).

That said, ssh -X should "just work"

Comment: No luck with this. :(